# What (old and new) Avengers are in the Captain America: Civil War movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

What former and new Avengers are in the new [Captain America: Civil-War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War) movie? And on what side are they in the "civil war"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Former Avengers:**

- Captain America <sup>Av1, Av2, CA1, CA2</sup>
- Iron Man <sup>Av1, Av2, IM1, IM2, IM3</sup>
- Black Widow <sup>Av1, Av2, CA2, IM2</sup>
- Hawkeye <sup>Av1, Av2</sup>
- Scarlet Witch <sup>Av2</sup>
- Vision <sup>Av2</sup>

### **Other characters from former Avengers movies:**

- War Machine <sup>IM1, IM2, IM3</sup>
- Winter Soldier <sup>CA1, CA2</sup>
- Falcon <sup>CA2, (AM)</sup>
- Agent 13 <sup>(CA2)</sup>

### **New Avengers:**

- Ant-Man <sup>AM</sup>
- Black Panther
- Spider-Man

**Avengers not in this movie:**

- Hulk <sup>Av1, Av2</sup>
- Thor <sup>Av1, Av2</sup>

---

All characters are divided into two sides, one for regulation of super-heroes and one against:

> **Against regulation:** Captain America, Hawkeye, Scarlet Witch, Winter Soldier, Falcon, Agent 13, Ant-Man
>
>  **For regulation:** Iron Man, Black Widow, Vision, War Machine, Black Panther, Spider-Man

---

**Footnotes:**

- <sup>Av1</sup>: [The Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_(2012_film))
- <sup>Av2</sup>: [Avengers: Age of Ultron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron)
- <sup>CA1</sup>: [Captain America: The First Avenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger)
- <sup>CA2</sup>: [Captain America: The Winter Soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_Winter_Soldier)
- <sup>IM1</sup>: [Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_(2008_film))
- <sup>IM2</sup>: [Iron Man 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_2)
- <sup>IM3</sup>: [Iron Man 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_3)
- <sup>AM</sup>: [Ant-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant-Man_(film))

---

All information here was from the two [official](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43NWzay3W4s) [trailers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKrVegVI0Us) and other sources like the articles on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War) and [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/). After the release of the movie it has be confirmed as correct.

Comment: Hawkeye was briefly in Thor

Comment: Isn't Falcon an Avenger? He is seen in Ant-Man protecting a Stark Industries warehouse, and Tony Stark is (as for Avengers 2) supporting financially the Avengers? More generally, how are Avengers super-heroes distinguished from non Avengers super-heroes distinguish in the movies? For example, War Machine belongs to the US army but, due to the shadow nature of SHIELD (pre and post Captain America 2), couldn't he be an Avengers too?

Comment: @Taladris I went by "which character was in one of the Avenger movies" (Av1 and Av2 in the footnotes).

Comment: Nailed it. *swish*

Comment: Needs update since movie's out now. Also, aren't War Machine and Falcon bot Avengers? They're even in Av2.

Comment: @RedCaio: Both were only in the epilogue of Av2, that's why I didn't count them.

Comment: Falcon may have only been in the epilogue, but War Machine was in the whole movie and even fought in the actual battle above Sokovia. So he's in the movie. I'd even say that pretty much makes him an Avenger too.